# Using Python 3.7 pip to get a library

Tags: python, pip

Python noob here.

I need to install the `microbit` library for MicroPython. I think Python uses "pip" for package management. I think its supposed to just work for me in 2020 but it doesn't. I can't get pip recognised on Windows 10, I've tried:

```
# From Windows 10 PowerShell
> py --version
Python 3.7.0

> pip
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....etc.

> py -3 -m ensurepip
Looking in links: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwmmqz_qq
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)

> py pip
(null): can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I also downloaded a `get-pip.py` script from another SO answer, ran it, it exited without output but doesn't seem to have done anything.

```
> py .\get-pip.py
>
```

After which `pip` and `py pip` are still not recognised.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: What does `py -3 -m pip` do?

Comment: Make sure pips location is part of your path variable.

Comment: @cwalvoort I was asking about `py -3 ... pip`, not `... ensurepip`. :-)

Comment: Have you config your env varible path ?

Comment: @erip Shows the usage help as if bad syntax.

Comment: I don't know what path would need to be in my PATH

Comment: I know nothing about micropython, but the `(null)` is something I've seen in other distributions of python which means you don't have a virtual environment setup which will likely restrict you in installing garbage into the global distribution.

Comment: @erip I'd just ignore the micropython part, its just Python 3.7 on Windows and trying to run pip to get a library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+The+term+%27pip%27+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that though `py` is in the PATH and just works, the `pip.exe` is not and doesn't just work. So after searching for its executable, I've found it here and it runs.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Thanks!